# How can I write a dictionary to a csv file?

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionary looks like the following.

```
res = {'Qatar': ['68.61994212', '59.03245947', '55.10905996'],
'Burundi': ['0.051012487', '0.048311391', '0.046681908'],
'Japan': ['9.605144835', '9.247590692', '9.542878595', ]}
```

I want to get rid of ' [ ] in my csv file

I want to get the output csv as,

Qatar    68.61994212   59.03245947    55.10905996

Burundi  0.051012487   0.048311391    0.046681908

Japan    9.605144835   9.247590692    9.542878595

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert dictionary to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120783/python-convert-dictionary-to-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`[(k,) + tuple(res[k]) for k in res]`

You will get list of tuples likes this which you can write to a csv file:

`[('Burundi', '0.051012487', '0.048311391', '0.046681908'), ('Japan', '9.605144835', '9.247590692', '9.542878595'), ('Qatar', '68.61994212', '59.03245947', '55.10905996')]`

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below. The reason you are getting '[]' is because you might be trying to write the val of the dictionary as-is which is a list. Instead you need to retrieve the values in the list and then write it.

```
import csv

res = {'Qatar': ['68.61994212', '59.03245947', '55.10905996'],
'Burundi': ['0.051012487', '0.048311391', '0.046681908'],
'Japan': ['9.605144835', '9.247590692', '9.542878595', ]}

with open('./result.csv', 'w') as res_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(res_file)
    for k, v in res.items():
        res_val = [x for x in v]
        res_val.insert(0, k)
        csv_writer.writerow(res_val)
```

**OUTPUT**:

The contents of the file (result.csv) are as below:

```
Burundi,0.051012487,0.048311391,0.046681908
Japan,9.605144835,9.247590692,9.542878595
Qatar,68.61994212,59.03245947,55.10905996
```

Comment: @DIG Then it would make sense to mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from [Jay-s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205848/5223309) answer if you are allowed to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) then you can use panda-s `to_csv` function to just make the csv in one line.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df.to_csv('my_result.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will do it:

```
import pandas as pd

res = {'Qatar': ['68.61994212', '59.03245947', '55.10905996'],
       'Burundi': ['0.051012487', '0.048311391', '0.046681908'],
       'Japan': ['9.605144835', '9.247590692', '9.542878595', ]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res, orient='index')
df.to_csv('res.csv', header=False)
```

Be sure to use "orient='index'" when creating the dataframe so that you get the correct row indexing in the csv

```
Qatar,68.61994212,59.03245947,55.10905996
Burundi,0.051012487,0.048311391,0.046681908
Japan,9.605144835,9.247590692,9.542878595
```